# Which are the best SIP providers

Tags: android, sip

I am trying to build up an application using SIP. In android developer's site [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) its mentioned that

> *Each participant in the application's communication session must have a SIP account. There are many different SIP providers that offer SIP
>   accounts*.

So, which are the best SIP providers from whom I can get free accounts and integrate with my SIP app.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do internet calls, you can use free services like 
[IPTel](http://www.iptel.org/), [Ekiga](https://ekiga.im/index.php?page=services)

They provide free lifetime accounts.

If you want to have free VoIP calls but with the possibility of paid external calling you can use services like [OnSIP](https://www.onsip.com/getonsip), but depending on the dimension of your user base, you should look for alternatives.